# ObjectListview checkbox column not change state when click

Tags: c#, objectlistview

i'm using ObjectListview to display checkboxes for columns but there is a problem.

My model is like this:

```
public class HocVienLopDTO
{
    public HocVienDTO HocVien { get; set; }
    public double Diem { get; set; }
    public List<NgayHocDTO> DSNgayHoc { get; set; }
}

public class NgayHocDTO
{
    public DateTime Ngay { get; set; }
    public bool CoHoc { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a listview like this: `(Diem, DSNgayHoc[0], DSNgayHoc[1], ...)`. And i want to use checkbox for all the DSNgayHoc column to present value of it's CoHoc property. So i dynamically generate columns like this:

```
this.lstvDiemDanh.UseSubItemCheckBoxes = true;
    List<OLVColumn> colList = new List<OLVColumn>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.lop.DSNgayHoc.Count; i++)
    {
        OLVColumn col = new OLVColumn();
        col.IsHeaderVertical = true;
        col.CheckBoxes = true;
        col.AspectName = string.Format(string.Format("DSNgayHoc[{0}].CoHoc", i));
        col.Text = this.lop.DSNgayHoc[i];
        col.Width = 20;
        col.IsEditable = true;
        colList.Add(col);
    }

    this.lstvDiemDanh.AllColumns.AddRange(colList);
    this.lstvDiemDanh.RebuildColumns();
```

All the checkbox was displayed fine but their state is not changed when i clicked them. (Always square box). I tried to handle ChangingSubItem event to change the currentValue and newValue but no luck. Please help!

Sorry about my english.

Comment: Do the check boxes correctly reflect the initial state of CoHoc?

Comment: No. Initial value of CoHoc is false and the checkbox was checked by a square and i cannot change it!

Comment: Are you sure that the HocVienLopDTO objects you are adding to the ObjectListView actually have items in the DSNgayHoc list and its not NULL or empty? Are you adding the `this.lop` to the OLV? You probably do not only add one model object? A "square" checkbox indicates that the OLV has a problem accessing the value behind the AspectName.

Comment: Yes. When i tried to use a bool property directly in HocVienLopDTO, it works fine. But if i try to access CoHoc from HocVienDTO's DSNgayHoc, it doesn't work. Maybe OLV doesn't support getting aspect from the child collection?

Comment: Ah yes, now I see it. You really can't set a AspectName like that. The OLV is using reflection to search for a property with that name. This can't work this way, it does not know you are accessing a list index. But there is a workaround. AspectName is only for simple use cases. I will post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OLV is using reflection to search for a property with the `AspectName` name. This won't work in this case, because it does not know that you are accessing a list index.

Instead of using the `AspectName`

```
// ...
col.AspectName = string.Format(string.Format("DSNgayHoc[{0}].CoHoc", i));
// ...
```

you have to use the `AspectGetter` and `AspectPutter` callbacks to access the `DSNgayHoc` list as desired.

```
// ...
int listIndex = i;
col.AspectGetter  = delegate(object rowObject) {
    HocVienLopDTO model = rowObject as HocVienLopDTO;

    if (model.DSNgayHoc.Count > listIndex)
        return model.DSNgayHoc[listIndex].CoHoc;
    else
        return false;
};

col.AspectPutter = delegate(object rowObject, object value) {                    
    HocVienLopDTO model = rowObject as HocVienLopDTO;

    if (model.DSNgayHoc.Count > listIndex)
       model.DSNgayHoc[listIndex].CoHoc = (bool)value;
};
// ...
```